# Shadow Rendering optimization

Tags: opengl, shadow

Ok this is basically an engine design question. I came to the point that it's time to optimise rendering process and have started with shadows. Currently my engine only renders shadow maps. For aproximately 5 projected shadow maps and 5 cube map shadows I get around 235FPS on my GT 640 (all shadows are 512x512 resolution). If I change resolution to 2048x2048 I get 55FPS which is actually quite good. But I am still considering to redesign shadow map rendering entirelly and this is why I have opened this topic just to discuss. There are two approaches that I am thinking about and I would like you to share ideas or experiences.

First approach is based on what I call straight-forward shadow mapping approach. Each light has it's own framebuffer object, with 16-floating point RG texture (for variance shadows). One idea that pops to my mind is to have 2 fbo's of some sort. If the light is completelly static I would render only static objects and save depth buffer (static objects depth buffer). This would only need to be rendered once. Now I render second framebuffer with only dynamic objects and merge it with "static depth buffer" (ofcourse use static depth buffer when rendering dynamics to do early-z test and discard fragments). Whenever an object inside lights frustum moves or another object gets into frustum the step is repeated. "static depth buffer" is copied, dynamics are rendered and merged with static. In this way I could avoid rendering static objects over and over each frame. But my consern here is memory overhead. Thinking about a scene with 50+ lights (some of them point lights with cubemap shadows) and probably colossal amounts of memory would be used.

Second aproach would be as I found it on the internet a little ago it was called "Importance shadow mapping" I guess. The engine has for example 10 projected shadow maps and 5 cubemap shadows prepared. When doing the frustum culling and list of objects and lights to be rendered, 10 projected lights and 5 point lights get assigned to shadow maps waiting. This way engine is limited to a few shadows only and memory is saved. But in this case I can't implement separated static and dynamic shadows system. Or maybe I could combine both methods and per each light only save "static depth buffer" and combine it with engines shadow maps?

With the second approach, another thing that pops into my mind is to detect which shadows fall into cameras field of view. For example: A cube is visible to the light, but not to the camera. Obviously a shadow of the cube might be visible on the final image. It depends on how light and camera are positioned and rotated. Sometimes cube's shadow might affect the final image other times not. My idea is to do a simple test on CPU to determine if shadow is visible or not. Doing a simple edge detection I can create a polygon from lights point to cubes AABB edge and into the distance (clipped by the lights range). I could then detect if this polygon intersects with cameras frustum to determine if shadow is visible to the camera or not and so discard it from rendeing into the shadow map.

These are some quick ideas and I would like your thoughts on them? What could be done and what is worth trying.

Comment: For bounty comment - here is the actual link https://mediatech.aalto.fi/~ari/Publications/Shadow_Caster_Culling_for_Efficient_Shadow_Mapping.pdf